# Issue with ivreghdfe Command in Stata: "option requirements not allowed"

Tags: stata

I'm currently working with the ivreghdfe command in Stata 18. Unexpectedly, I've started to face the following error, even though the same code and database didn't produce this error just a week ago:

```
option requirements not allowed
r(198);
```

To troubleshoot, I've updated the ftools, reghdfe, ivreg2, and ivreghdfe packages, but the issue persists.

Has anyone encountered this issue previously or have any insights into potential causes?

**Solution:** Issue with ADO files when installing packages using ssc install

I ran into an issue with the ado files when I tried to install certain packages via ssc install. Instead, I found success by using the net install command directly from the creators' GitHub repositories.

Here's the code for those who might run into the same problem (https://github.com/sergiocorreia/ivreghdfe#installation):

```
* Install ftools (remove program if it existed previously)
cap ado uninstall ftools
net install ftools, from("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sergiocorreia/ftools/master/src/")

* Install reghdfe
cap ado uninstall reghdfe
net install reghdfe, from("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sergiocorreia/reghdfe/master/src/")

* Install ivreg2, the core package
cap ado uninstall ivreg2
ssc install ivreg2

* Finally, install this package
cap ado uninstall ivreghdfe
net install ivreghdfe, from(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sergiocorreia/ivreghdfe/master/src/)
```

Comment: Please give us a reproducible example with dataset and exact command typed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the solution and have updated the post with it!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Issue with ADO files when installing packages using ssc install

I ran into an issue with the ado files when I tried to install certain packages via ssc install. Instead, I found success by using the net install command directly from the creators' GitHub repositories.

Here's the code for those who might run into the same problem (https://github.com/sergiocorreia/ivreghdfe#installation):

```
* Install ftools (remove program if it existed previously)
cap ado uninstall ftools
net install ftools, from("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sergiocorreia/ftools/master/src/")

* Install reghdfe
cap ado uninstall reghdfe
net install reghdfe, from("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sergiocorreia/reghdfe/master/src/")

* Install ivreg2, the core package
cap ado uninstall ivreg2
ssc install ivreg2

* Finally, install this package
cap ado uninstall ivreghdfe
net install ivreghdfe, from(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sergiocorreia/ivreghdfe/master/src/)
```

Comment: Good that you've solved your problem, but you don't, so far as I can see, explain what the "issue" is and why your code is a solution. Possibly a programmer is updating code in one place and not another.